# Google Tag Manager Session end

Tags: google-tag-manager, logout

Just wanted to implement a logout feature to my website. So if you end the session it automatically logs out so just wanted to know how to end a google tag manager session or logout(You know what I mean. please help !!! )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Tag Manager does not keep sessions, it strictly operates page based and does not persist anything from page to page (unless you implement it yourself via custom html tags). So there is no GTM session you need to end.